# Powershell - convert military time string to datetime

Tags: datetime, powershell, time

I'm looking for a method to convert a military time string ("22:12:02") into a datetime object.

Here's an example of the code:

```
$TimePrevious = $Null
[array]$TimeArray = "22:12:02.000", "22:12:03.000", "23:12:02.000"

$TimeArray | ForEach-Object {
    $TimeCurrent = $_.Substring(0,8)
    $TimeDifference = [datetime]$TimeCurrent.TimeOfDay - [datetime]$TimePrevious.TimeOfDay
    If ($TimeDifference.Second -lt "10") {Write-Host "$_ is less than 10 seconds"}
    $TimePrevious = $_
    }
```

The error reads "Cannot convert the "22:12:02" value of of type "System.TimeSpan" to type "System.DateTime"

Comment: I wonder why you call that "military"? It's a regular time format.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: **exactly!!** The **whole world** (except for the US) basically uses the 24-hour time format ... it should be called **Standard time format** or something ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default parser seems to work with that:

```
[datetime]"22:12:02"
```

Thursday, March 07, 2013 10:12:02 PM

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I just got this to work:

```
$TimePrevious = $Null
[array]$TimeArray = "22:12:02.000", "22:12:03.000", "23:12:02.000"

$TimeArray | ForEach-Object {
    $TimeCurrent = $_.Substring(0,8)
    $TimeDifference = [datetime]$TimeCurrent - [datetime]$TimePrevious
    If ($TimeDifference.TotalSeconds -lt "10") {Write-Host "$_ is less than 10 seconds"}
    $TimePrevious = $_
    }
```

Thanks for the fast replies.